# Webpack devServer - separating entry files from the asset files

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have the following dir structure...

```
/dev
    /assets
        [all imported static assets, like WOFFs, SVGs, PNGs etc...]
    /css
        styles.css
    /js
        bundle.js

/src
    /sass
        styles.scss
    /js
        scripts.js

index.html
```

...and the following Webpack configuration (really simplified):

```
{
    context: './src/',
    entry: {
        'js/bundle.js': './js/scripts.js',
        'css/styles.css': './sass/styles.scss'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '../[filename]',
        path: './',
        publicPath: '/dev/assets/'
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('../[name]')
    ],
    ...
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './',
        publicPath: '/dev/assets'
        ...
    }
}
```

The concept here is that every file will be placed to the `dev/assets` folder by default, but in case of the entry files, I have the option to group them to other folders (under `/dev`), described by their entry object key (the trick is the `../[filename]` value of the filename property).

This gives me full control over the folder and name structure of the `dev` files, and also collects the rest of the files (static assets like font files, SVGs, PNGs etc) to the `dev/assets` folder.

This works as expected with normal Webpack builds, but the same configuration will not work with Webpack dev server, as it will only serve the files of `dev/assets`, and the files of it's sibling folders (like `dev/js`) cannot be accessed.

Is it possible to somehow make the dev server work with the described functionality?

**Update**

index.html, at @Chris R's request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/dev/css/styles.css">
    <script src="/dev/js/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide your index.html? Or at least the parts where you request your js and css files?

Comment: @ChrisR Of course, updated the question. But there's really nothing special here, except for that Webpack generates static CSS files with extractTextPlugin().

Comment: Thanks for the update, this will change my answer.

Comment: There were some mistakes in `index.html` with the filenames, re-edited the question

Comment: Why do you want to have control over the dist folder ? Is it going to change ?

Comment: I use this Webpack config in my frontend framework, which need to be flexible enough to work with different file structures. What else would you offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I used `/dev/assets` as publicPath was to automatically collect all asset (not entry) files to an `assets` folder. (The entry files files got a `../` prefix, see in `output.filename` to pretend a relativity to `/dev` instead of `/dev/assets`).

After some investigation I realized that I could rather set a different `outputPath` for `url-loader` and `file-loader` in the specific `module.rules`, where I generate the asset files, so I could remove this ugly hack from the webpack config.